# Javascript/html: How to store div, and hide its children later

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am storing a div which gets selected

```
var selectedCell = null;
    $(".selectableBox").on('click', function (event) {
            selectedCell = $(this);
        }
```

Later I want to hide one of selectableCell's children name selectableCellChild

```
$('#deleteConfirmed').on('click', function (event) {

    selectedCellList.($'selectableCellChild').hide();
});
```

How can I correctly hide this child div?  I know the syntax of the above example isn't right, and I have tried it many ways including using children() and next() methods of selectedCellList

Comment: provide your HTML markup as well please

Comment: @Shyju. It's probably just too tested so `children` doesn't catch it (and obviously so does `next).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
selectedCellList.find('{selectableCellChild}').hide();
```

Where `selectableCellChild` is a placeholder for the real selector of the cell.

> I have tried it many ways including using **children()** and **next()**

- `children` - traverse only one level deep.
- `find` - traverse the all the DOM levels deep.
- `next` select the next immediate sibling.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.find`.

```
selectedCellList.find('selectableCellChild').hide(); // I hope selectableCellChild isn't your real selector, it won't work
```

Also, when declaring your variable, make it a jQuery object since you intend to store a jquery object in it to avoid undefined method errors.

```
var selectedCell = $();
```

Comment: Since jQuery 1.4, empty jQuery object is simply: `$()`

Comment: @gdoron Thanks, I'm too used to having to have all of my code work on older versions due to the way things get copy/pasted around here.

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, this is what you want:

```
$('#deleteConfirmed').on('click', function (event) {
    $(selectedCellList).find('.selectableCellChild').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to hide the children of clicked div. Try like below,

```
var selectedCell = null;
$(".selectableBox").on('click', function (event) {
   selectedCell = $(this);
}); //Your missed );

$('#deleteConfirmed').on('click', function (event) {
   //v-- Changed from selectedCellList to selectedCell as this is the clicked div.
   selectedCell.find('.selectableCellChild').hide(); 
   //assuming selectableCellChild-^ is class of child elements in the clicked div
});
```